# Logging in vernemq plugin

Tags: erlang, mqtt-vernemq

I am trying to implement logging on connected users in my vernemq client using erlang. From documentation, I found that this could be bad, due to the scalability of the client and the assumption that there might be a lot of clients connecting and disconnecting. This is not my case, I will just have a bunch of clients but a lot of messages. Anyway, to my question. Is it possible to change the log file when using `error_logger`? Or should I use a different module for logging? Log file can be in any location if it had to, but I need it separated from vernemqs `console.log`. A followup question would be, can I somehow get a floating window on logs? I don't need to keep logs from previous year and I don't want to manually clean them every day or week or something like that

Thanks for any responses

Answer (score 0):

From OTP21 on, you should use `logger` instead of `error_logger`, although the `error_logger` API is kept for compatibility (it justs uses `logger` under the hood).

With `logger`, which you can [configure](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/logger_chapter.html#configuration) with the system configuration, you can use file backends such as [`logger_std_h`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/logger_std_h.html) (check the [example configurations](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/logger_chapter.html#configuration-examples)).

In `logger_std_h` you can set file rotation.

Comment: May I ask you where exactly to put it? I am very new to erlang, as you can probably see. I tried putting what is in documentation as an example into my rebar.config file (I use rebar3 for that plugin), but I see no file with the log entry (I tried searching with grep -r on the entire system).

Comment: @OndřejChládek This is application configuration, so it should be placed in the sys.config files. You have [documentation and examples for rebar3](https://rebar3.org/docs/deployment/releases/#application-configuration)

Comment: I tried to insert example configurations into `config/sys.config` and run `rebar3 compile` but it did not pass any config to the compiled version. At the documentation, they seem to use `rebar release` but if I use the release files, verne cannot find the plugin. Putting sys.config into compiled plugin also did not resolve the issue. I am just trying to write simple plugin but I cannot figure this out. Thanks

Comment: @OndřejChládek I misunderstood the nature of the plugin, in that case you can use [application:set_env/*](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#set_env-4) from your code (although I don't recommend it) or search and edit vernemq's sys.config file

Comment: After thinking twice about it, you may want to use [logger's configuration API](http://erlang.org/doc/man/logger.html#configuration_API) instead to set up your plugin logs separately from the rest of the system's (but modifying the system's log config is better done through sys.config)

Comment: Thanks! will take a look on it and hopefully resolve the issue